# What is the relation between multiplexing and the sampling frequency in a data acqusition system?

Tags: sampling

There is a data acquisition board recording analog signals from 10 channels with multiplexing. If one wants to sample each channel with for example 2000Hz and the number channels is 5 should the sampling frequency be set to 5x2000=10000 for the board? I have a confusion with the skew and sampling. here is the device specs I'm talking about: http://www.mccdaq.com/usb-data-acquisition/USB-1616HS-BNC.aspx

Comment: Probably not, but I've seen it both ways.  The docs should absolutely clarify, as should sampling a sine wave on two channels and making sure your sample rate isn't off by a power of 2.

Comment: here is the device specs: http://www.mccdaq.com/usb-data-acquisition/USB-1616HS-BNC.aspx

Comment: Can't help-- I won't register to download the user manual, but guaranteed it's in there.

Comment: whats in there? if u wanna know  its a typical daq system there is a multiplexer which multiplexes one by one each channel and sends the data to adc. isnt it enough to answer my question????

Comment: @user16307 "it" is the answer to your question.  You're asking about how the software or SDK communicates with the devices.  Usually, any box that you type in that says "sample rate" or library call with a sample rate argument refers to samples per second for each channel.  Since we're talking about software here, only the documentation can tell you for sure.  The 1MS/sec maximum rate spec, by the way, may well be for one channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture a sinewave of 2kHz then sample as fast as you are able and at the very least you'll need to sample at 5kHz (to avoid unwielding brick-wall filtering on the front end of your ADC).

If you don't sample at a high enough rate you'll get [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) so, try and sample as fast as you can - that's one channel. Aliasing: -

[image]

For ten channels feeding the ADC via a multiplexer then you need to sample ten times as fast as you were for one channel.